# Can I remove some of the strange attributes from a strange cosmetic?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have a strange haunted Templar's Spirit that I like, but it has pre-existing strange attributes.

They are carnival kills, carnival game wins, and carnival underworld game kills. But I can't access them anymore (iirc) because that promotion is over.

I want to replace these strange parts with something else (hopefully something like allied healing done), but the 3 attributes already being used.

Can I clear/overwrite/remove the current trackers?

Comment: Halloween comes every year.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ yes, but the same event is doubtful. I don't think the strange parts will update.

Comment: On halloween you can usually play all halloween-themed maps, including Carnival of Carnage. It's one of the few ways you can get the achievements related to this event too.

Comment: @Sumurai8 In the same update Valve added these cosmetics, they also made it so that Halloween maps automatically activate Halloween mode when they're being played.  In other words, as long as you can find a server running the map, you can level up the stranges by going to Carnival of Carnage.  Easiest way?  Search the Server Browser for servers playing `sd_doomsday_event`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most cosmetics, @EnragedTanker's answer would be correct.

Strange Haunted items are special.  Why? Because they have the following intrinsic properties/parts that can't be removed:

- [Strange Filter](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_Filter): [Carnival of Carnage](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Carnival_of_Carnage)
- [Strange Part](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_Part): Carnival Underworld Kills
- Strange Part: Carnival Games Won

Why? Because they were part of the Halloween 2014 event, which introduced sd_doomsday_event AKA Carnival of Carnage.

Comment: So can I add 3 more strange parts? Or only 1 more? Or no non-halloween themed ones?

Comment: @RikerW It looks like you can add one more strange part to it.  However, due to the effects of the Strange Filter, it will only work on Carnival of Carnage AKA `sd_doomsday_event`

Comment: Having said that, I don't really want to spend money just to get Strange Parts to test that theory. I know you can add at least one part because I get prompted to add some when I right-click one of my Strange Haunted items.

Comment: lol I'll buy one, maybe I can just use it later. Will it only work on the carnival or any halloween theme?

Comment: @RikerW As far as I can tell, just on the one map.  That's what Strange Filters do other than give the weapon a funny name.

Comment: Okay, I'll test it this halloween. :P

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

> Strange Parts can be individually removed from a weapon using the
>   Restore button in the backpack, allowing the player to remove a
>   strange part of their choosing; however, a part which has been removed
>   will not be returned to the player, and instead will be permanently
>   lost.

-- [Strange Part](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_Part), Team Fortress 2 Wiki

Right click on the strange item in your backpack, click Restore, choose the part you want to remove.

Comment: This menu item doesn't pop up. All I get is "Inspect", "Go to loadout", "Rename", "Change description", and "Delete".

Comment: @RikerW are you using a custom HUD?

Comment: @Robotnik no, the default one.

Comment: @RikerW Could you link a screenshot to either a comment or the original question? [Edit: Just saw Powerlord's answer. Never mind. :P ]